# Main markup cannot be empty. If you are trying to delete the Lightning definition bundle, directly delete the bundle instead

Tags: lightning-aura-components, deployment, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When I run this command:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml
```

I get this response:

```
PROJECT PATH     ERROR
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────   
N/A              Main markup cannot be empty. If you are trying to delete the Lightning definition bundle, directly delete the bundle instead    
N/A              Main markup cannot be empty. If you are trying to delete the Lightning definition bundle, directly delete the bundle instead.
```

The project path is `N/A` and I am deploying hundreds of files, so I have no idea where to look.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the `Aura Lightning Components` was missing it's `.cmp` file.

Once the remaining files and folder were deleted, the issue went away.

Comment: Aye! Make sense :) I faced same few days back.

Answer (score 1):

The Command is correct. However, There seems to be a Lightning Bundle folder present in deployment source path with incomplete/missing/deleted bundle files.